# how to delete a user in a mysql server based on search results?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, groupbox

[image: sample]

I have a datagrid control with a list of names that it retrieves from a MySql database. I can search through them until i have one result. I want to be able to Display a groupbox control when the number of results is equal to 1. Also, in the groupbox i have a button that when clicked will delete this user from the server and their information from the mysql table called "employee". when the user is deleted i'll display a confirmation message in a messagebox, and reload the table with the updated list. so far the only two problems i have are showing the groupbox when the results are equal to 1 and deleting the user from the sql server based on the name of the search result.  im using vb.net in visual basic 2010 express on windows 7 laptop. Thanks!

**EDIT1:**

Heres my code so far, please suggest how i can apply your answers to it. Thanks!

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    'Search Function.
    Dim sqlsearch1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee where name LIKE '%?name%' GROUP BY name;", con)
    Dim sqlsearch2 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee where title LIKE '%?title%' GROUP BY title;", con)
    sqlsearch1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", TextBox1.Text)
    sqlsearch2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?title", TextBox1.Text)

    If RadioName.Checked = True Then
        con.Open()

        Dim table As DataTable
        For Each table In ds.Tables
        Next
        ' Clear all rows of each table.
        ds.Clear()

        ' display results in Datagrid1.
        DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sqlsearch1
        DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "stratos")
        DataGrid1.DataSource = ds
        DataGrid1.DataMember = "stratos"
        con.Close()
    Else
    End If

    If RadioTitle.Checked = True Then
        con.Open()

        Dim table As DataTable
        For Each table In ds.Tables
        Next
        ' Clear all rows of each table.
        ds.Clear()

        ' display results in Datagrid1.
        DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sqlsearch2
        DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "stratos")
        DataGrid1.DataSource = ds
        DataGrid1.DataMember = "stratos"
        con.Close()
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

for deleting, you can simply issue a delete statement and pass it a parameter, namely name.

`DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyName = @Name`

Im not sure what you need the group box for.

Comment: i want to show a group of controls when there is only one result in the datagrid control. Also, im a little confused as to how i get @name out of the datagrid... like how do i get a certain column in a datagrid?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx To get column and row index of a selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something like

```
 Set recBooks = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE Name like 'hey' ;")
```

recbooks.count will return the number of records.

And for deleting, just run the query

```
  DELETE FROM Admin WHERE Name = {0}
```

when the button is clicked, and reload the datagrid using datagrid.refresh()

Comment: your code makes no sense, theres no "Set" function that is native to vb.net i think your talking about the "list Of(Strings)", function. Also "Execute" isn't a member of the mysqlconnection function. If you could elaborate a little bit more as to how i could apply your code to my problem then please do so. also, im updating my question with my script so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, dataset doesn't have a way to check for number of rows. Try using sqlsearch1.Executescalar()

The code would be :
     num_rows = ConverttoInt32(sqlsearch1.Executescalar());

Based on that, you can either do the datagrid.fill or not.

Comment: Ok, I don't know which libraries you are using. But, this was the reference I learnt from. http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4

Search for executescalar()